# woocommerce twocheckout return payment error, but mail send

Tags: php, wordpress

i choose a payment method with twocheckout plugin for woocommerce , the payment proccess it is ok, i can make the paymanet via sandbox with the plugin the issue is on the return payment of the process :

```
Order properties should not be accessed directly.
Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-load.php'), 
require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), 
do_action('wp_loaded'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, 
call_user_func_array, WC_Form_Handler::checkout_action, 
WC_Checkout->process_checkout, WC_Checkout->process_order_payment, 
WC_Gateway_Twocheckout->process_payment, WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, 
wc_doing_it_wrong
```

and wordpress drop an error

```
"Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent"
```

but the payment is ok, and the order got placed, acctually even the orders mails go sent,

thanks for the support and the hel

Answer (score 0):

after reading the get methods of twocheckout function plugin for woocommerce, i realize there is nonupdated methods for call for Order properties,so , to check errors should go to 
[WC order methods of Woocommerce](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html) and check the change, :

the "process_payment" function for twocheckout have deprecated methods for calling billing address info , so here's the update :

```
            if ( 'yes' == $this->debug && $this->notify_url !=='')
            $this->log( 'Generating payment form for order ' . $order->get_order_number() . '. Notify URL: '. $this->notify_url );

        // 2Checkout Args
        $twocheckout_args = array(
                                'token'         => $_POST['token'],
                                'sellerId'      => $this->seller_id,
                                'currency' => get_woocommerce_currency(),
                                'total'         => $order->get_total(),

                                // Order key
                                'merchantOrderId'    => $order->get_order_number(),

                                // Billing Address info
                                "billingAddr" => array(
                                    'name'          => $order->get_billing_first_name() . ' ' . $order->get_billing_last_name(),
                                    'addrLine1'     => $order->get_billing_address_1(),
                                    'addrLine2'     => $order->get_billing_address_2(),
                                    'city'          => $order->get_billing_city(),
                                    'state'         => $order->get_billing_state(),
                                    'zipCode'       => $order->get_billing_postcode(),
                                    'country'       => $order->get_billing_country(),
                                    'email'         => $order->get_billing_email(),
                                    'phoneNumber'   => $order->get_billing_phone()
                                )
                            );
```

also you can find the updated methond on the forkedre [here](https://github.com/balusio/woocommerce-2checkout-api/commit/cb6f29e08ae5548b00dd051f737de242f23a793c)

hope this get updated soon.